# JavaScript game object with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need to create a gameplay object that consist of several buttons, or a sprite that will react differently to clicks on the different parts of the sprite. I am using the Phaser framework. I have a very simple sprite representing a chip, with two small inputs, a main body (rectangle), and a small output. I want to have the game do different things depending on which part is clicked. Is the best practice to create different buttons and sprites for each item and somehow group them together? Or can I use one sprite, and somehow define different functions for each part?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `<>` in the editor - right now your question is off topic as soliciting opinions rather than answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless ways you could accomplish that. Here is only one of them.
Using canvas to draw the spirte, and detecting the click evnet location based on the x,y position within the black area of the sprite.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game_canvas');

var cnvLeft = canvas.offsetLeft,
  cnvTop = canvas.offsetTop;
var chip = {
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  width: 90,
  height: 40
};


var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(chip.x, chip.y, chip.width, chip.height);


canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - cnvLeft,
    y = event.pageY - cnvTop;
  if (x > chip.x && x < chip.x + chip.width / 2 && y > chip.y && y < chip.y + chip.height) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
    ctx.fillRect(chip.x, chip.y, chip.width / 2, chip.height);
    console.log('You clicked my left side');
  } else if (x > chip.width / 2 && x < chip.x + chip.width && y > chip.y && y < chip.y + chip.height) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
    ctx.fillRect(chip.x + chip.width / 2, chip.y, chip.width / 2, chip.height);
    console.log('You clicked my right side');
  }
})
```

```html
<h3>Click the black area</h3>

<canvas id="game_canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is something I can try to work from.